# Show a specific slide on load, pause and then scroll through all slides and start at the beginning with Timeline.js

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am building a corporate website and one section is a "History" page. I am using [Timeline JS](http://timeline.verite.co/) to do so. I've been very successful in getting it work by pulling a JSON feed from my Wordpress install; however, there's one thing that I can't figure out. My client wants to show a "cover image" and say something like: "Explore our History", wait a few seconds and then have the timeline auto-scroll to the very first slide at the beginning of the company's history.

I've read in the [docs](https://github.com/VeriteCo/TimelineJS) that I can specify a start slide and I can have the timeline start at the end, but I need to write some kind of callback function that runs after it starts on the slide I want it to. I am thinking I might be able to do that in the start_at_slide option, but I'm not sure how to go about it:

```
var timeline_config = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "580",
  source: "/plugins/timeline/timeline.json",
  start_at_slide: $(function(){
     // some code that says, start at the last slide, delay and then scroll to slide 1
  });,
  hash_bookmark: true,
  start_zoom_adjust: "2",
  css: "/plugins/timeline/css/themes/font/Helvetica.css"
}
```

Another option might be to write a separate function outside of the timeline_config that overrides the normal behavior, but before I go down that rabbit hole, I wanted to see if you guys have any suggestions.

Once I get this up and running, I plan to release this as a Wordpress plugin since the options out there for TimelineJS and Wordpress are less than ideal.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Make a use of

```
this.setSlide = function(n) {
        goToSlide(n);
    };
```

on ***/complied/js/timeline.js***
I just took a look into the js file and I think manipulating this would do the trick.
I'll try to do what you want when I get some time tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, I think that might work. I'll give it a shot and let you know if it does.

Comment: For those of us arriving here from a search, I'd love to know if this answer worked for you.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot... I had a request to hide completely slides (but not the prev/next buttons)... I did just add a flag to conditionally perform the lines: preloadSlides();                                VMM.fireEvent($slider, "MESSAGE", "TEST");
at the bottom of goToSlide(), et voilà...

Comment: what is the object I call it at? is it VMM.setSlide(0)?